# Why is this image here?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, images

I came across [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/310014/revisions) edit page and it looks to me like there is an image in it that should not be there. I think this might be a bug because in this window we should see the raw text of the image aka the link to it.

this is what it looks like to me: [image]

Maybe I'm mistaken and someone can explain this?

Comment: it's showing because it was the OP's original post and they uploaded that image there and stuck half the minecraft comment as the alt text. as for why who knows, people can be weird sometimes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the post history. Version 1 had the picture. Version 2 had the picture. Version 3 removed the picture.

Comment: They're also looking at revisions 2 and 3 in 'Side-by-side Markdown'. If they switch it to 'Inline' or 'Side-by-side' they will see the rendered text and image.